# Is there a way to keep the app data even after uninstallation?

Tags: apps, storage

I have a game that I'd like to temporarily uninstall, but I want to keep its app data. When I re-install it later, I can have everything that I had in the game before the installation. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Xbox games (Kingdoms & Lords etc.) providing cloud storage of game data. But not all. This is the only possible way to achieve this. Back up of application data is still not supported even with GDR-3.